# my computer just shuts down randomly

Tags: windows-7, laptop, shutdown

i have a windows 7 32 bit machine (running on a compaq615)

it used to work great but now it just shuts down even i the easiest tasks
i tried switching to windows 10 pro 64 bit it works but still shuts down
i also tried linux and still the same

i thought it was a heat issue so i took it to a store to change the thermal paste
but still nothing , i tried changing the ram and replacing the battery but still the same

so its not the ram or the power (im also using its og power brick) and not the thermal issue (it shuts down in windows recovery and in the installations and even right when i turn it on like after a minute but it is still cold not so hot)

so is there anything that i didnt try that might help the problem i really dont want to replace it

Comment: It sounds as though your computer has hardware faults. Inspection and repair by a competent hardware technician is likely required. It could still be a cooling issue. It could be power. It could just be age. Your computer is 10 years old, though, so the question must be whether it is worth the likely cost of repair, especially considering it is a laptop, which is generally going to be more difficult and expensive to repair.

Comment: i have a hp pavilion dv4000 and it works like a charm i reall dont think its the age , and for the cooling it used to work great before and the temp was 95 C (i got this from open hardware monitor) and i recently sent it to a technician but he said it was ok (i hate them , i really hate technicians , they just scam you I PAID HIM TO ADD A 4 GB RAM BUT HE ADDED A 2 GB RAM WHAT A SCAM)

Comment: so i think im better of getting a new one and selling the parts

Comment: Comparing one very old computer to another doesn't prove anything. Your Compaq is old. You will also have to hate me if you hate technicians. Depending on the transaction and the age of the computer you may simply be dissatisfied because the outcome wasn't what you wanted. It is entirely possible for memory ports to fail and for memory chips of the correct type not to work. Ranting without substance in here is a quick and sure way to get your posts closed. Old computers require special care, and even then they can and do fail. It's life.

Comment: hi music2myear thanks for your answer but i think its not the case as i didnt really damage my laptop PHISICALLY (no drops water spills etc..) and i had the OG ram stick in it when it happened

Comment: No one guessed you had damaged the computer, and damage isn't required for issues to occur, merely age. Your computer is old.

Comment: one thing to add i noticed that the random power shut down (or whatever you wanna call it) occurs less when i use another lighter OS other than windows 7 that it shipped with so may it be a faulty power controller ?

Answer (score 1):

this is the best info i can give at the moment since you don't have much info on when it started (eg. "i installed some program and bla bla bla") and whatnot, but let's get the elephant out the room with everything i have so far

- first things first you should always contact whoever manufactured the pc, check if it still applies to warranties yada yada yada, if you used [dual booting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k8J8fG5nPyo) when trying to switch operating systems then you might want to run an antivirus scan (i use kaspersky), if not go to the next dash on the list
- this seems to clearly be an issue with the hardware or something like a corrupted hard disk drive, and it is a disk or anything like that you might want to wipe the drive or reset it to factory settings via your os of choice

Comment: i really dont think its like that because i recently reinstalled windows (as a single boot) and i reformated my drive (full format not a fast one)